# Creating subsets of dataframes from a single dataframe based on the distinct values of a column

Tags: r

I am creating the subsets of dataframes based on the distinct values of a column using the below code --

```
divide <- function (agg,"campaign"){
  #get the set of possible values
  column.levels <-if(is.factor(agg[,"campaign"])) {
    levels(agg[,"campaign"])
  } else{
      unique(agg[,"campaign"])
  }
  # A list used to store each individual dataframe
  res <- list()
  #iterate through all possible values and store each subset in a separate
  #entry in the list
for (val in column.levels){
  hits <- agg[,"campaign"] == val
  #store data set temporarily in a local value
  data.set <- agg[hits,]
  str(data.set)
  #assign levels to the cloumn, this adds levels to string data
  levels(data.set[,"campaign"]) <- column.levels
  #store the data set in the list
  res[[val]]<-data.set
}
#return list
res
}
```

So the problem i am having here is --

I have created a list() with these 7 distinct values
but i am unable to create 7 dataframes from this list! The only dataset that was created is the last "val" on the "column.levels"

Did anyone face the similar situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use lapply, which will return a list of data frames using your function (there is no need to predefine res as a list):

```
res = lapply(column.levels, function(val){
    hits <- agg[,"campaign"] == val
    #store data set temporarily in a local value
    data.set <- agg[hits,]
    str(data.set)
    #assign levels to the cloumn, this adds levels to string data
    levels(data.set[,"campaign"]) <- column.levels
    #return list item
    data.set
})
```

As you haven't supplied dummy data, I haven't tested the above.

Comment: I tried the above code, dataframes are created, but i couldnt view those.

Here is a sample data-

campaign      IS    LISR  LISB
Belts              90    5        5
Belts               95   2.5     2.5
Books            80   10     10
Books            70    15     15 
Bags              75    12      13
Bags              65     15    20

I want belts, books, bags into different dataframes... in my case as there are many distinct campaigns i am using the above code!

Comment: If you're getting a list of data frames back then `res[[1]]` will return the first data frame in your list. The data you supply need formatting to make your problem repeatable.

Comment: Thank you very much Mike. I was looking for that, got the required dataframes!

Comment: No problem. You can now work on your list of data frames using lapply in the same way. Also, if you're happy with my answer can you mark is as such?